# What distribution and link function should I used for analyzing proportions?

Tags: r, distributions, proportion, generalized-additive-model

I have a dataset were a small number of individuals were sampled each year for their sex. I would normally use a binomial model (link = logit), to analyze sex ratios, however, in this system, the ratio of F:M varies by size class. Therefore, to estimate the overall proportion of females in the population, I need to account for the total number of individuals in each size class in each year.

I'm wondering if a gamma distribution would be appropriate with a log link function would make sense using the estimated proportion of females (pF) in the population?  Or should I try something else entirely like a Beta distribution (link ??)...

Ultimately, I'll be modelling this data with a general additive model (GAM).

Example dataset:

```
set.seed(42)
# dataframe with individuals sexed in each year
dfSex <- data.frame(
  year = sample(2003:2012, 2000, replace = TRUE),
  size = c(rep(LETTERS[1], 1000), rep(LETTERS[2], 1000)),
  sex  = c(sample(c("F", "M"), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9)),
           sample(c("F", "M"), 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)))) %>% 
  group_by(year, size) %>% 
  summarise(nF = sum(sex == "F"),
            nM = sum(sex == "M"))

#dataframe with the number of individuals in each size class/year
dfCounts <- data.frame(
  year  = rep(c(2003:2012), 2),
  size  = c(rep(LETTERS[1], 10), rep(LETTERS[2], 10)),
  count = sample(100:1000, 20))

df <- left_join(dfSex, dfCounts) %>% 
  # calculate overall proportion of females after accounting counts of individuals in each size class
  mutate(cFsize = nF/(nF+nM)*count) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(cF = sum(cFsize),
            cT = sum(count),
            pF = sum(cFsize)/sum(count))

df
# A tibble: 10 × 4
    year    cF    cT    pF
   <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
 1  2003  423.  1376 0.308
 2  2004  581.  1342 0.433
 3  2005  641.  1056 0.607
 4  2006  183.   705 0.259
 5  2007  322.   909 0.354
 6  2008  259.   634 0.409
 7  2009  473.  1137 0.416
 8  2010  633.  1663 0.381
 9  2011  194.   878 0.221
10  2012  691.  1817 0.380
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow why the binomial is not sufficient here; that model is for counts from a total, which seems to fit with each observation being a count of females from a total number of individuals in that class. Assuming you know the total number of individuals in the size class, you can pass that to the weights argument while the response is the proportion of females out of that total number of individuals.

Comment: I think that would work if I was planning to include females for each size class in the model separately, but for this analysis the response if actually the total # or proportion of females in the population after accounting for the combined contributions of the size classes.